# How to pass 2values to window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I have a script in which I have to pass 2 values to window.location.href to open a new window which accepts these two values from the URL.

```
onclick="showrestdetail($urlpagename)"
```

The function is as follows:

```
function showrestdetail(urlpage)
{
    window.location.href=urlpage;
}
```

But I want two values to be passed in this function and catch thse two values when new window opens.
Is there any way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No I can't pass values using QueryStrings.

Comment: Please provide me another way

Comment: Any reason why you cant use query string?

Answer (score 3):

Pass your values in the query string.

```
http://www.domainname.com/pagetopassto.html?FirstName=Super&LastName=Man
```